# Integrated Projects of openstack on the last release of The Canonical Distribution of Ubuntu Openstack

Tags: openstack, canonical

What are the different projects of openstack included in the last release of The Canonical Distribution?

I didn't find if Trove, Heat, Ceilometer, Sahara and some features of Neutron (Firewall as a service, Load balancer as a service, SDN, IPv6) are included in Canonical distribution.

Answer (score 2):

Our experimental ppa contains support for 'contributed' plugins to the installer. So far we have Heat, Ceilometer, Mongo, and a few others. Once we release 1.0 the plugins will be available in our stable repo.

You can install the experimental packages to mess around with them:

https://launchpad.net/~cloud-installer/+archive/ubuntu/experimental

We'd love to have more external contributions related to OpenStack services. You can see a current list of charm 'plugins' that are available here:

https://github.com/Ubuntu-Solutions-Engineering/openstack-installer/tree/master/cloudinstall/charms

I should also note that this doesn't speak for Landscape OpenStack Autopilot just for the Single and Multi installation methods.